# while loop with relational operators

Tags: c, while-loop, boolean

```
int I;
I=0;
while ((CH1[I]=CH2[I]) != '\0')
      I++;
puts(CH1);
```

This program is to copy CH2 in CH1 but I didn't understand the loop condition `(CH1[I]=CH2[I]) != '\0')`?

Comment: Consider `=` versus `==`

Comment: This looks like an overly compex form of the Kernighan strcpy: `while (*dst++ = *src++) {;}`

Comment: the = assignment @AlexReynolds

Comment: `CH1[I]=CH2[I]` copies the value from `CH2` element to `CH1` element, and if it is 0, (nul string terminator) quits.

Comment: @wildplasser how can I read (understand) it?

Comment: The assignment `=` returns the value that was assigned. This is then compared with `'\0'`.

Comment: The syntax says `while(expression) {...}` and an  assigment has a value, thus is an expression.

Comment: Spaces are cheap; use them.  And names with all capital letters (plus digits and underscores) are conventionally used for macros and enumeration constants, not for variable names.  (`for (int i = 0; (ch1[i] = ch2[i]) != '\0'; i++) ;` would be more idiomatic C, assuming you can't simply write `strcpy(ch1, ch2);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `while` loop condition contains of two parts:

```
CH1[I]=CH2[I] // this is an assignment that copies character at Ith position in array CH2 into array's CH1 Ith position
(...something...) != '\0' // checks if 'something' is not equal to '\0', the string termination character.
```

Therefore `while((CH1[I]=CH2[I]) != '\0')` copies characters one at the time from `CH2` into `CH1` and breaks as soon as it copies over '\0', which means end of string was reached and there are no more characters to copy.

Comment: but isn't this the syntax of while loop :
while (condition)
{statments}
sorry I'm new in C programming :p

Comment: @Elliot95 and, in the end, the statement **is** a condition with side effects.